# Add Event on HTML string of javascript (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to call the event in the string of JavaScript.

On the `buffer` I called this event:

```
@click.prevent = "Buy($event)"
```

But browser won't parse it:

[image]

code attempt:

JS:

```
    var buffer="";
    for(let i=0 ;i < Object.keys(result).length;i++) {
        buffer += "<div class='category-item'><a class='button-product-info-s' href='/product/"+result[i]['id']+"'/><img class='product-img-s' src='"+result[i]['pic_url'] +"'></a><p class='product-name-s'>"+result[i]['name']+"</p><a @click.prevent='Buy(event)' href=''  class='btns btn-primarys btn-buy-s' value='"+result[i]['id']+"'>Buy</a></div>";
    }
    this.codes= buffer;

//Buy function

Buy:function (event) {
    element= event.currentTarget;
    value = element.getAttribute('value');
            }
```

HTML:

```
    <div v-html="codes"></div>
```

**Problem is brower won't realise that i called the event on the `<a>` tag not an attribute**

`result` is my API data.

Comment: Is result an array or object?

Comment: Define "Browser won't parse it". And when are you executing this JS? Are you adding this to the DOM on the client side, or on the server side? You're attempting to have the browser dynamically parse strings into Vue code; I don't know if Vue would do that.

Comment: @ssBarBee an array

Comment: @DaveNewton im adding this to client side https://ibb.co/Kj6j3Wc

Comment: @DaveNewton i got the data with API and i want to execute on them by running 
 a function do you have better idea for call the function on string?

Answer (score 0):

As I guess, you could try `@click.prevent = "Buy($event.target.value)"`. instead of just `$event`. To correctly diagnose the problem I think I need more related code, like the `Buy` method.

Comment: i added the buy function

Comment: I don't know, try replacing `element= event.currentTarget; value = element.getAttribute('value');` with just `value = event.target.value`. Why do you use `currentTarget` instead of `target`? Btw did you call `Buy($event)` or `Buy(event)`?

Comment: my problem is not about the function if you look at this picture you will find out https://ibb.co/Kj6j3Wc

Comment: brower shouldn't show the @click that means brower won't parse it for some reason

Comment: Oh, it seems you added vue code to v-html where it expects only vanilla html. Can you produce the full runnable code so that I could easier tweak around?

Comment: i have 10 line code to get the result from an api and i dont think it will work

Comment: Just push all of your code to jsfiddle and leave them here, produce the full runnable code. Your code smells too much typo vulnerable so it might be just some trivial tiny bug.